# LinkedIn registration plugin

Tags: facebook, registration, linkedin-api

Facebook has amazing registration plugin http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/

Does linkedIn has some similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. You could build your own, but there isn't one you can use out-of-the-box.